# How to disable battery full notification sound?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, notifications, battery, audio

When battery has been charged full, my Galaxy S phone gives the same notification sound that is used when I receive SMS. Is there a way to disable the sound without also disabling sound from SMS? It usually charge the phone during night and wake up easily to the "Battery fully charged. Unplug charger" notification sound :(

Comment: Anyone know if this just for the galaxy s?  I don't think I've ever seen this in stock Android or cyanogenmod?

Comment: Must be. My Droid doesn't do that.

Comment: My Galaxy Tablet turns the screen on after fully charging while I'm trying to sleep at night: pretty stupid!

Comment: @PPO1: My Galaxy S phone used to to that too, but that went away after upgrading to Froyo 2.2 ( or 2.2.1 - don't now exactly but it did went away after an upgrade ).

Comment: I have a Galaxy Gio running FroYo, and I think this may be a Samsung 'feature.'

Comment: my galaxy-fit has the same issue

Comment: For the record -- LG L5 with Android 4.0 has also fixed audio notification :-(

Comment: I have the same problem. My battery seems to run out so quickly these days that my phone is constantly bouncing from full to low. So strange that it thinks the battery-state-change is as 'important' as a message. My phone is more demanding than a toddler!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From what I can find, there is no way to turn it off:

no solution in the [samsung galaxy s forum](http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/samsung-galaxy-s-how-to/suppress-100-battery-notification/)

no solution in the [vodafone forum](http://forum.vodafone.co.uk/topic/65933-samsung-galaxy-s-battery-full-notifcation/)

[Tasker can't suppress it](http://groups.google.com/group/tasker/browse_thread/thread/9c2a2a87f77cd94e/27f345b2159f0627)

However, one commenter notes

```
Some custom ROMs rebuild the framework and rip the notification out entirely. 
Check out the XDA forums if you'd like to try that stuff.
Typically requires root and a good working knowledge of how to use
Clockwork Recovery, Odin, etc... not for the faint of heart.
```

Comment: Oh bummer. Well, I used Tasker to suppress notification sounds during night. That is not a perfect solution as I cannot then hear SMS sounds, but at least I can now sleep :D

Comment: My Serendipity ROM (http://serendipityrom.weebly.com/) removes the battery full sound.  A lot of work for one simple thing, but if one is considering a custom ROM anyway it's something to consider.

Comment: Too bad - I have the same issue with my Samsung Galaxy Gio and I would love to get rid of the notification sound. Will the Gingerbread update help fix this?

Answer (score 17):

1. Set the global notifications to silent.
2. Set the notification on messaging to any ringtone (not default).
3. Repeat (2) for any other app you want notifications for.

You'll still have a tone when you 1st plug the phone in to the charger, but no tone when it's fully charged.  Of course, this isn't a perfect solution since you need to manually set every other app, and presumably some won't have individual notification settings.

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this question because I want to recharge my phone at night next to my bed. Therefore, I do not want it to wake me, but setting the phone to silent does not solve it, as I want to be reachable for emergency calls.

My solution (which isn't strictly a correct answer to the question, but might solve the problem for most people) was using the app "Night Ringer Free", which enables me to enter a whitelist for calls/sms, however, all other sounds are silenced.

Answer (score 5):

From the XDA Developers Forum, I have implemented [this solution](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1386112) successfully on my Samsung Galaxy S Epic 4G (with GingerBread.EI22 and also GingerBread.EL30), which has eliminated the "Battery fully charged. Unplug charger" notifications from my phone.  The solution offers the following three features:

1. Stops the vibration.
2. Silences the sound.
3. Prevents the screen from turning on in the middle of the night.

Best of all, you may choose to implement any (or ALL) of the three features above.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Try Sound Manager. Schedule volumes of types of sounds with it (6 categories). Switch off notification (Battery full, e-mail notification etc.) volume from 12 to 7 while leaving untouched ring and media volumes and you're all set. Works on my brandnew Samsung Galaxy s2.

Slept well  last night without a disturbance! I used to swich to buzz only before going to sleep and to remember to switch it back to ring in the morning.

Sleep well!

Answer (score 3):

Since updating my SGS from 2.2 to 2.3, I no longer get the charged notification sound, so I'm assuming they fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

- '**GravityBox**' Xposed module (available separately for Lollipop, Kitkat and Jelly Bean) that has an option for exactly that
  (Under `Power tweaks -> Battery Charge sound tick`).
- Or an even more dedicated module [Disable Battery Full Alert](http://repo.xposed.info/module/uk.co.villainrom.pulser.disablebatteryfullalert) module.

For information on how to install 'xposed' modules, view a similar [stack exchange post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/41869/temporarily-cache-notifications/62206#62206).

Comment: This is the most precise solution, that doesn't involve silencing your phone or whatnot. It disables specifically that notification, because [Samsung doesn't care](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=General&messageId=278749&messageNumber=10752#post10).

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung Charge, and was able to disable the annoying "Battery Full" notification by using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en).  As others have stated, the Tasker solution I used is not specific to disabling only the BatteryFull notification when reached, but it *does* limit the amount of time notifications are disabled and when.  What I did with Tasker:

1. Contexts-Power, Time between 11p-6a, Battery between 99-100% ...Task - disable notification
2. Contexts - Power, Time between 11p-6a, Battery Full ... Task - enable notification.

This should limit the amount of time notifications are disabled to only a few minutes, since it only takes that long to charge the battery from 99 to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

I found something in [these forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1103166) that involves rooting your phone to accomplish this task.  Keep in mind this is specifically for the Droid Charge.  However, you may be able to apply it your phone.  The basic principle involves rooting your phone and changing some system sound files with [Root Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer).  There was another answer that involved rooting your phone and installing a custom ROM, but I would wager that this is possible without the custom ROM.  Installing the custom ROM is the much more difficult step in my opinion (although I've personally done it).

Comment: It is not clear from your answer what kind of steps are you suggesting to take. Can you be more specific, please?

Comment: What is that "some system sound files"?