# Other than the external LED indicator, how can I be notified that my phone is done charging?

Tags: battery, notifications, charging

I'm wondering if there is a setting that I am missing that allows an Android phone to produce an audio notification (or even vibrate) once charging is complete. As is stands, whenever charging is complete the external LED on most phones (such as the HTC Droid Incredible) changes from orange to green. The use-case is when the phone is charging across the room or in another location that's out of sight.

Comment: Someone had the opposite problem with their Galaxy S: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-to-disable-battery-full-notification-sound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe my phone vibrates when it's done charging, but I've never seen a setting for it.  I'm certain you could set up a profile with Locale to notify when charging is done.

Comment: Or Tasker. I'm going to have to pony up for one of those. They're the answer to so many questions here.

Comment: Slightly on topic... I hated the Notification and Alert Dialog that TouchWiz does when the phone finished charging. It even wakes the phone, which is not good if you have "stay awake" on...

Answer (score 2):

If you use Tasker automation app you can implement an alert using it - [Battery Full Alert](http://tasker.wikidot.com/battfull).

Free alternative is the app called [AutomateIt](https://market.android.com/details?id=AutomateIt.mainPackage&hl=en). It also has a battery level trigger based on which you can produce a notification/sound, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app called [Battery Charged Notifier](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.wesleywiser.batterycharged&feature=search_result) that will just notify you when your battery is fully charged. It is free, but there is a "paid key" that adds some additional features, like setting your own notification sound.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and the -1. This app has very bad reviews. Going to keep searching.