# How do I stop my phone from beeping when it completes charging?

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-2, audio, charging

I have a Samsung Galaxy 2 S running Android 2.3.

When I plug it in to recharge, it beeps when it reaches 100%.

I would prefer that it not notify me with a sound.

However, I can't for the life of me find anywhere that this is set.

Is it possible to disable this annoying chime?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable battery full notification sound?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-to-disable-battery-full-notification-sound)

Comment: Realise it isn't an exact dupe as one's for a Galaxy S 2 on 2.3 and one's for a Galaxy S on 2.1 or 2.2, but this does seem to be a feature that Samsung put into all their firmwares for a while, so the answers over there should be the same for you.

Comment: I don't know if this should be closed maybe... it seems that with recent firmware updates the problem has gone away.

Comment: which is why for people like me who actually liked the beep, there's an opposite question [How do I turn on the battery full notification sound?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9563/). As not everyone will have updated their firmware, and as Samsung may bring this back in the future (hopefully with an option to enable/disable) I'm not sure this needs to be closed.

Comment: @GAThrawn: Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>[Here's](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/tools/battery-charged-silencer_bcgac.html)</s> [Here's](https://market.android.com/details?id=cz.psencik.simple.silencer) [tnx @GAThrawn] a free app that claims to be able to do that.