# Disable turn on when charging finishes

Tags: standby

When my Android phone is charging, the moment it becomes fully charged, it 'wakes up'
from standby mode. This is  annoying, because 
I often let it charge at night in my room, and it wakes me up. Is there a way to prevent this from happening without powering off my Android phone? Thank you!

Comment: See [How to prevent brightness when battery reaches high?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/133382)

Comment: No, that's not what I'm talking about. What I mean is that it leaves standby IR turns on mode when it's fully charged.

Comment: Suppose my phone is 56% charged, and I plug it in to the charger, then I put it in standby mode, then when it becomes 100% charged, it will suddenly cease to be on standby mode for a few seconds, then it will 'go back to sleep.' This happens on my phone, and I want it to stop.

Comment: So you want your device to not end the standby mode when battery reaches 100% since it causes the device to turn on the screen at high brightness which wakes you up. Correct? Tell me please, doesn't the linked question actually tries to *tackle the original problem* which is about high brightness disturbing sleep?

Comment: It turning on wakes me up regardless of how bright it is. I am am one of those people who are easily woken up. Thank you, though.

Comment: A [quick search on our site](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[charging]+complete+answers%3A1) turns up: [How do I stop my phone from beeping when it completes charging?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/11992/16575) (with further links). [Another search](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=[charging]+full+answers%3A1) to check. No full match, though.