# How do I get rid of the "Battery fully charged, unplug charger" popup screen?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, charging, screen, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Every time my Note 2 gets fully charged, it beeps and (more annoyingly) turns the screen on to tell me to unplug it now that it's fully charged.

1. I'm not going to unplug it overnight.
2. I don't want that happening in the middle of the night waking me up.
3. I also don't want that happening during the day at work.

How do I disable any and all notifications that it's fully charged?

Comment: Older but possibly relevant: [How to disable battery full notification sound?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/how-to-disable-battery-full-notification-sound)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option to try:

Go to Settings> Sound> Battery Full Notification. Un-check this option and see if that fixes the issue the next time you charge your Note.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [Xposed Module](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) and go into the Download section. There's a module called "Disable Battery Full Alert". Try installing that module, then reboot your phone.
See if it works.

Comment: It's worth noting that the phone needs to be rooted to use Xposed. The questioner didn't say if his phone is rooted or not.