# Temporarily cache notifications

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

Is there a way to completely block notifications on my Android device? I'm not asking for "silent mode" or "remove individual apps, one by one". What I'd like, ideally, is an app that disables temporarily (like Windows 8 does) for say, 1, 3 and 5 hours all notifications.

This includes sound, vibration, LED blinking, and the notification "banners" that appear on the notification area. Except obviously the permanent notifications, like Avast!, alarm clocks and TuneIn (just to name a few). And then, after the timer expires, show all notifications that have been blocked.

Even if root is required, is there any possible way to achieve this? When I'm studying, I really hate having pending notifications in my bar, so instead of dismissing it, I'm forced to check them. I think Honeycomb tablets with the merged bottom bar had the feature to turn off notifications (although not temporarily, it was as easy as flipping the switch on when you were done).

Edit: I'm running Android 4.2.2 AOSP (no root but I know how to root it) on a Nexus 7. Fully OEM.

Edit 2: There is definitely no notification toggle on my device.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: It's likely that the answer will depend on the version of Android OS your device is running, so it would be helpful to know this.

Comment: There is actually a Notification toggle right in the notification bar. Just tap the notification bar, then the large Time display, then switch `Notifications` to **Off**. You wont receive notifications from it again until it is turned on. For automation, refer to [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

[Notifications Off](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aboutmycode.NotificationsOff) is an android app available in play store, it will help you to make profiles so that you can block Some/All app notifications.

***ROOT is required for the app to work.***

---

There is feature called "Quiet hours" in CM 10.1 .

It's available for your Nexus 7. Just install that ROM and set a time interval.
During that time period you can mute notifications, notification light and disable vibrations.

**Settings**-->**Sound**-->**Quiet Hours**

*OR*

If you prefer to use ASOP, you can uncheck the **`Show Notification`** option in Apps info.

Comment: Sorry, as stated in my question, this is not what I want. This will mute and stop vibration by notifications, but will still show them in the notification area. What I want is temporarily be able to hide all incoming notifications (so that nothing appears on the top bar distracting my attention).

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
The closest solution would probably be to use 'GravityBox' (which is an Xposed module for android). This is by far the most Utile Xposed module I found. **One of its** many **features** is to **block incoming notifications** completely/partially! I highly recommend it whether you want a notification blocker or not!

(Visit [GravityBox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2316070) for more information)

**Requirements:**

- Rooted android smartphone
- Xposed framework *Easy to install... just download the apk from [Xposed Installer](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401)*
- GravityBox *Can be installed using Xposed*

**To install GravityBox:**

1. from the Xposed Installer app, visit the 'Downloads' tab and simply search and Download 'GravityBox' module
2. Switch to the modules tab and tick to enable the 'GravityBox' Module
3. Open the 'GravityBox' App and navigate to Statusbar Tweaks->Ongoing notification blocker
4. Customize the blocking of notifications
5. Restart your phone and experience notification blocking

Comment: I actually use GravityBox myself, but this does not solve it, as it only blocks ongoing (AKA permanent, static) notifications, like Avast!.
I want to block push notifications, like when you have a new mail, or there's new updates for apps in the Play Store. Ongoing notifications don't bother me at all, in fact, but thanks!

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Great question!!

Answer (score 0):

There's an app called notif log that I'm using for the exact same reason. The only thing it doesn't have is the ability to keep them from popping up initially, But it does allow you to snooze them for later or retrieve them if they were dismissed. I just snooze them and then dismiss. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dvdh.notiflog