# Is there a way to block USSD balance notifications on Android 4.3?

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, ussd

I'm trying out a H20 Wireless SIM on my Nexus 4 running Android 4.3.  One annoying feature of this service is that they send a USSD balance notification at the end of every phone call, text message, and data usage.  Is there any way I can disable or block these messages?

I found the "Balance Update / USSD blocker" app in the Play store, but it specifically states it does not work on 4.2+ versions of Android.

I also contacted H20 customer service and they will not disable the messages on their end.

Comment: You cannot certainly disable that as that is carrier specific regardless of what version of Android is used. *But* having said that, there was a USSD exploit last year which enabled remote execution of ussd codes to factory reset devices (*this was on Samsung*) by clicking on a linky, the newer Android versions since JB have sanitized the process in mitigating that exploit and subsequently handled differently. It would have held true in Eclair/Froyo/GB and ICS.

Answer (score -1):

**Easy method** (requires **root**)
Yes, there is an app for exactly that and much more called 'GravityBox' (it is an Xposed module).

For information on how to install it, view a similar post [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62206/52084)

**Alternatively** (does **not require root**)
If you are lucky your Phone app should have a "Blacklist" to which you can add numbers and prevent calls and/or messages (notifications) from them. Normally found in the settings of your default phone app...
If you don't have it, then you could even try a **3rd party phone app** that will replace your default phone app that will do the trick (There is a large variety that are more beautiful, simplistic, up-front and have features including **black-listing options**...).
*Using a 3rd party phone app will leave all your contacts intact, but you may loose your speed dial settings.*

Comment: Using Xposed requires root and the OP did not give any indication of status of rooted device.

Comment: Sorry. I have taken it into consideration and have edited my answer to be a little more broad.

Comment: Please mention how to use GravityBox to block those USSD notifications/messages. I do not see any relevant option inside it.

Answer (score -1):

Try Out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.paco.ussd&hl=en

It blocks all USSD Notifications

Comment: this link may answer the Q but better you write a brief about it and also should disclose your association if any, with the app